# How to get a rectangle move up to a point and then down again?(and this over and over)

Tags: java, animation

This is my code but I can't figure it out how to get the rectangle to move up and then move down!

My Rectangle class:

```
public class Block {
    private int size;
    public int xpos;
    public int ypos;
    boolean up = true;
    public Block(){
        size = 40;
    }
    
    public void drawBlock(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(xpos, ypos, size, size);
        
    }
    public void setStartScrLocation(){
        xpos = 130;
        ypos = 200;
    }
    public void startAnimationUp(){
        ypos = (int) ((int)ypos - 0.0001);
    }
    public void startAnimationDown(){
        ypos = (int) ((int)ypos + 0.0001);
    }
}
```

and this is my "startscreen class":

```
public class startScreen {
    Block startBlock = new Block();
    public startScreen(){
         startBlock.setStartScrLocation();
    }
    public void displayThings(Graphics g){
       
        startBlock.drawBlock(g);
        if(startBlock.up == true){
            startBlock.startAnimationUp();
        }
        else if(startBlock.ypos > 280){
            startBlock.up = false;
        }
        else if(startBlock.up == false){
            startBlock.startAnimationDown();
        }
        else if(startBlock.ypos < 200){
            startBlock.up = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The rectangle just moves up and then it stops at the top of my frame(I didn't post the frame class if you are wondering) my Frame's width is 300 and height is 500
I have got a paintComponent function in my frame class which draws this function displayThings

Comment: If I understood the logic right, once ypos gets above 280, your second condition will fire, but nothing else will. Therefore you'll never get to startBlock.startAnimationDown(); Personally, I'd just have your logic to set startBlock.up, then replace your two animation methods with one, and add or subtract dependent on the value of startBlock.up (if you get my drift). Call that method outside the conditional test...

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems.  Firstly, you start with `up == true`, which causes `ypos` to decrease on each iteration.  Since `ypos` starts at `200`, it will never get to `280`, so the condition to set `up` to `false` never arises.  So it will keep decreasing indefinitely.

Secondly, in your method to increase `ypos`, you are increasing it by `0.0001`, then rounding it down to the nearest integer below, which has no effect, so `ypos` would never increase even if `up` became false.